# Treat a whole "word" literally with regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to do a REGEXP match with MySQL against a variable, like so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE table.CONTENT 
REGEXP CONCAT('([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])', table.NAME, '([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])')
```

This works fine, but it's possible for table.NAME to have regexp special characters in it (e.g. '|'), in which case it gets all screwed up.  Is there a regexp operator to treat an entire sequence of characters literally and ignore operators within it?

For example, if table.NAME was 'left|right' for one row, I would want it to only match if table.CONTENT literally has the string 'left|right' in it.  But unless I can force that somehow, MySQL would see that as an operator and look for either 'left' or 'right'.

Comment: Are you aware that REGEXP is slower than `LIKE`?  If you want better performance, I'd recommend using naming scheme that doesn't involve special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your string should have the pipe character backslash-escaped for use in the regexp. I don't see any mysql function specifically for escaping regexp strings, but you could try using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to add the backslash:

```
REPLACE( table.NAME, '|', '\|')
```

Comment: Right, but that's only one operator.  I'd had to do that replace on every operator (., ?, +, *, etc.) to escape them.  I'm looking for something like '^%all operators between these two symbols get treated as literal characters%$';  Starting to seem like it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.

Replacing special chars is endless ... so you could escape everything in your string

You could do something like :

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION myescape;
CREATE FUNCTION myescape(str varchar(255))
  RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE strLen    INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i         INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE newStr    varchar(255) DEFAULT '';
        SET strLen = LENGTH(str);

do_this:
  LOOP
        SET i = i+1;
        SET newStr = CONCAT(newStr,'\\',SUBSTRING(str,i,1));

    IF strLen = i THEN
      LEAVE do_this;
    END IF;
  END LOOP do_this;
  RETURN newStr;
END;

//
DELIMITER ;
```

This function escape all character of your string. So you can insert it in your REGEXP.

```
 REGEXP CONCAT('([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])', myescape(table.NAME), '([[:space:]]|[[:punct:]])')
```

Tell us if it answered your problem.

Good luck with your project.